# Thymeleaf's sec:authorize-url with Spring's @Secured

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm developing application using Spring MVC 4.X, using spring security 4.X for authentication/authorization and Thymeleaf 2.1.2 for view layer. I'm controlling access to controllers using `@Secured` annotion. Problem is, that Thymeleaf ignores these annotations when resolving `sec:authorize-url`  attributes. Does anyone has working setup for this?

My security config looks like this:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint" security-context-repository-ref="sessionRepository">
   <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
   <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="usernamePasswordDomainAuthenticationFilter"/>
   <logout logout-url="/logout"/>
</http>
```

and in servlet config, there is

```xml
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

Controllers look like this:

```java
@Secured("ROLE_EXAMPLE")
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {
}
```

We use this Setup so security protects all controllers globally plus every controller (or controller's method if needed) can restrict access more if needed.

Everything works fine, secured controllers are not accessible for user without speciified role, `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` is obviously configured correctly, because `sec-authorize="hasRole('EXAMPLE')"` works as expected (and it takes `@Secured` into account).

But I feel it is prone to error to declare role both in controller and in the template, so I'd much rather use `sec:authorize-url`. By debugging, I found out, that it checks 
if user `hasRole('USER')`, as declared in Security's xml config file, but it completely ignores `@Secured` annotations when using `sec:authorize-url`. In worst case, I could declare all the access in security's config file, but I like `@Secured` annotation much more.

Is it possible to make this setup work?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't supported by spring-security. So the thymelaf-dialect can't solve it.

Comment: This is sad :( So back to configuring access separately from the controllers... Thanks for info